# How to turn example.com/index.php?p=xxx to example.com/xxx/

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

How do I do this? There are many topics about this but I tried all of them and it did not work.

Can someone give me an elaborate and extensive answer as I have practically no experience with `.htaccess`?

Comment: There are many, many tutorials for this - the key words to throw into Google are ["search engine friendly urls"](http://www.google.com/search?q=search+engine+friendly+urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mind, so might need some tweaking

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This will (internally!) send `example.com/xxx` to `/example.com/index.php?p=xxx`

So in the `index.php` you can do whatever you want with the `$_GET['p']` as you would normally do but the user will see the site as `index.example.com/xxx`

Comment: thank you. this works but is there a way of making it work with or without a trailing slash?

also, what would the rule be for the reverse? that if people will fill in index.php?p=xx they will automatically be sent to /xx/ ?

Comment: and also, how would i change page.php?cat=x&page=3&sortby=bla to /page/x/3/bla/ ?

Comment: with the above solution, site.com/page/x3/bla would be internally rewritten as site.com/index.php?p=page/x3/bla so by doing a explode('/', $_GET['p']) you get all the parameters. Just make sure your url-structure is consistent. You can write a similar RewriteRule for handling urls with a ?p=... but there isn't really a reason for it.

Comment: how do i make that rule only apply to index.php though? because i want to add another rule to turn site.com/browse.php?cat=XX to site.com/browse/cat

i added another rule but it still follows the first rule and interprets it as www.site.com/index.php?p=browse/cat

thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?p=$1
```